# Warning messages when subsetting on integer variables

Tags: r, label, shiny

I have a small shiny application in which I'm displaying the variable names as checkboxGroupInput and based on the selection I'm subsetting the data table to only those variables and displaying it.

What I observed is when a variable of Integer type with a label is selected, there is a warning message on the RStudio console as :

```
Warning in formatC(x = c(36L, 29L, 20L, 25L, 48L, 42L, 19L, 26L, 36L, 39L,  :
  class of 'x' was discarded
```

If I change the variable type to character(in which case label is gone) in the data.table the warning goes away - What are these warning messages mean and how could I get rid of them without change the type of columns?
Here is my code :

```
 Server.R
  library(shiny)
  dft<-data.table(name=c("a","b","c"),age=c(10L,12L,13L))
  label(dft$name)<-"Full Name"
  label(dft$age)<-"Age of patient"
  shinyServer(function(input, output) {
     output$x<- renderUI({
     checkboxGroupInput("g1","g1label",names(dft))
   })
  output$y<- renderTable({
    if (length(input$g1 > 0))
     {subset(dft,select=c(as.vector(input$g1)))}
  })
 })

 ui.R
  library(shiny)
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
     uiOutput("x")  ,
     tableOutput("y")
  ))
```

Comment: `subset` isn't really meant for use in programming...or at least its behavior can be unexpected in any context other than interactive use. You might want to switch to `[` extraction from the data.frame instead.

Comment: How would you create a sub data.table based on the selection from checkboxGroupInput values, I tried `quote(list(input$g1))` that didn't work. I would like to use [ if there is a way to dynamically subset